# Calling https rest api using node js - request npm

Tags: node.js, node-request

We are trying to access a HTTPS REST API(GET) using nodeJS with request module, but it is throwing 401 - unauthorized.

We tried various options - provided like oauth_token OR user id & password, everything returns the same 401 status. I have given below the code snippet any suggestions would be helpful.

**Note**: We are running behind a proxy and we have set http proxy env variables, not sure if this will have anything to do with 401 (I don't think so but I am not 100 percent sure)

```js
var request = require('request');
var options = {
 uri:  'https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json',
 auth: {
  user: 'test',
  pass: 'test-1',
  sendImmediately: false
 }
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Response is " + response);
    } else {
  console.log("Error is" + error);
  console.log("Body is" + body);
  console.log("Full response is" + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
 }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to go through the authentication flow for yammer here: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2
Then you'll need a Authorization header with a bearer token.

Comment: Thanks much it works.